# Help in mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database:

http://d.pr/86DH+

I want to divide all numbers in price column with 1.2 at once. It is possible?

Comment: And do what with it? In a select? Update the table with the new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET price = price / 1.2
```

Comment: Thank you, and Can I use select and update command in one query? This no working: SELECT * FROM  `product` LIMIT 0 , 5 AND UPDATE `product` SET price=price/1.2

Comment: @Adrian: If you need to select the "changed" data - use `SELECT price / 1.2 AS price FROM product`. This will return modified data without real modification it in the table.

Comment: No, I want to select first 5 line and then update (to test the result).

Comment: You've written "I want to divide **all** numbers". You really need to stop changing your requirements each second. Go to your initial question and ask what you **really need to do**

Comment: To select "first 5 lines" - just append `ORDER BY product_id LIMIT 5` to the former query

Comment: Adrian, why do you need to those 2 statements in one query?

Comment: You can use the UPDATE first, and then, the SELECT, using the same WHERE clausule.